# Front end, back end on same server with HTTPS and Websocket at the same time

Tags: docker, https, websocket, tornado

That’s said we have a website project. Front end will call the backend through Websocket protocol. In the backend, we have a Websocket server (through tornado) inside a docker container. The backend and front end are on the same server.

Here comes the problem, when we want to set up HTTPS for the whole application. The front end will use default 443 port and the backend will need 443 as well, which is conflicting each other. How should I do to avoid it? Is it possible to use wss (secure websocket) on other port when we initiate the request from client side (front end page to the backend) ?

By the way, the domain name is configured by another server.

Answer (score 0):

The port inside docker container with backend is 443 in the container. But you can set the local machine port. Use the flag -p:

```
docker run -d --name myName -p 443:445 image:tag
```

The port 443 of the container will listen trough the port 445 machine on your localhost. You can change the 445 for another you want.

You can local with localhost:445.....

Comment: How to change the port of websocket call?

Comment: I don't know. It depends on the language, framework and project configuration. Usually it should have a properties file with server url (localhost or 127.0.0.1), port, and more configuration parameters.

Comment: It's true for usual HTTP and HTTPS, but I am not pretty sure if it's the same for WebSocket.

Comment: Is the best. But you can use another and specify it when access by the url like this: https://www.example.com:7342/foobar.html. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/791218/can-i-use-another-port-other-than-443-for-ssl-communication)